# Text with string interpolation of Enum value, No exact matches in call to instance method 'appendInterpolation'

Tags: ios, swiftui, enums

I'm lost, why `Text("\(type)")` would get compile error meantime `Text(str)` is not. Did that string interpolation not create a string?

For the error please check screenshot in below.

```
enum ExpenseType: Codable, CaseIterable {
    case Personal
    case Business
}

struct AddView: View {
    @State private var type: ExpenseType = .Personal
    let types: [ExpenseType] = ExpenseType.allCases

    var body: some View {
        Form {
                ...
                
                Picker("Type", selection: $type) {
                    ForEach(types, id: \.self) { type in
                        let str = "\(type)"
                        Text(str)
                        // Compile error
                        Text("\(type)")
                    }
                }
                ...
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode fails to detect which `Text` initializer should be used, a rather annoying bug.

Possible workarounds:

1. Using [`String(describing:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init) initializer:

```
Text(String(describing: type))
```

2. Declaring a variable at first:

```
let text = "\(type)"
Text(text)
```

Comment: `String(describing:)` but why not just conform the enumeration to `String` does the exact same thing as described here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker

Comment: @cole This limits you to using only `String` as a base type, you may need to use some other type, such as `Int`, for other logics. My solution doesn't limit you to that. Also, this error does not only happen with enums, in that case your solution does not apply at all.

Comment: Yes, but he didn’t ask for that. Also you can just conform to Int in your enum. This won’t limit anything in my opinion. Not complex..

Comment: @cole I mean a case when you need to have `Int` raw value, like [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/6fc6e8a4687302e56e1274bf5319c472). How are you going to apply your solution in this case? I'm not saying that your solution should never be applied, but I find a cleaner solution when you don't need to modify the model.

Comment: OK, so it is a bug. Clearly string interpolation is assigned to that `str`, I think they are the same. However 1 Text is compiled and another not. Quite simple code, I have no clue what is the reason... @cole I'm asking why string interpolation is not worked and `Text(str)` is worked in this case, it is clearly said in my PO.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `rawValue`, and try to loop more efficiently over the `allCases`.

```swift
enum ExpenseType: String, CaseIterable {
    case Personal
    case Business
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var expenseType = ExpenseType.Personal
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker(selection: $expenseType, label: Text("Picker")) {
                ForEach(ExpenseType.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                    Text(type.rawValue)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think types is already with allCases `let types: [ExpenseType] = ExpenseType.allCases`, and may I know why string interpolation is not working? You could see if I assign that string interpolation to a string first, it would works in `Text`.

Comment: It's because you need to your `enumeration` to conform to `String`.